# Is $g(x, f(x))$ measurable if $f$ and $g$ are?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal Y)$ be two measurable spaces. Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is $(\mathcal X, \mathcal Y)$ measurable, and suppose that $g: X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ is $(\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$ measurable (where $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ is the Borel sigma-field over $\mathbb R$).

> Is the function $h: X \to \mathbb R$ defined by
>   $$h(x) = g(x, f(x))$$
>   ($\mathcal X, \mathscr B (\mathbb R)$) measurable?

This question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542571/show-that-fs-xs-is-borel-measurable), but I want to make sure that the same argument works for general measurable spaces.

The idea is that $H: x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ is measurable because both $\pi_1 \circ H = id_X$ and $\pi_2 \circ H = f$ are measurable, where $\pi_i$ are the projections and $id_X$ is the identity function on $X$. Then, $h = g \circ H$ is measurable.

Comment: Your argument is correct. $h$ is measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Follow-up question: Suppose $f$ is actually measurable in some sub-field $\mathcal X'$ of $\mathcal X$. Is $(x,x') \mapsto g(x,f(x'))$ $\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X'$ measurable?

Comment: You have to change the hypothesis on $g$ accordingly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not sure what I should assume about $g$. Any hints?

Comment: You have to assume that $g$ is $(\mathcal X' \otimes \mathcal Y, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$ measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347803/is-this-proof-of-measurability-correct).