# Is this proof of measurability correct?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal X)$, $(Y, \mathcal Y)$, and $(Z, \mathcal Z)$ be measurable spaces. Let $\mathcal X'$ be a sub-algebra of $\mathcal X$.

Let $a: X \times Y \to Z$ be $(\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y, \mathcal Z)$ measurable.

Let $b: X \to Y$ be $(\mathcal X', \mathcal Y)$ measurable.

> Is the function $c: X \times X \to Z$ defined by 
>   $$c(x,x') = a(x,b(x'))$$
>   $(\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X', \mathcal Z)$ measurable?

*Attempt.* First, let $d: (x,x') \mapsto (x, b(x'))$. Since $\pi_1 \circ d = \pi_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ d = b \circ \pi_2$, $d$ is $(\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X', \mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y)$ measurable (where $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$th coordinate). Then, $c = a \circ d$. So $c$ is $(\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X', \mathcal Z)$ measurable.

Comment: Yes, that’s a valid proof!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Ok, I hope so...I'm a bit worried about the first step since KaviRamaMurthy indicated in the linked thread that further assumptions on $a$ might be needed.

Comment: Which thread are you referring to? I don’t see a link.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346915/is-gx-fx-measurable-if-f-and-g-are?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I see. There would be an issue if you claimed that $c$ is $(\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Z})$-measurable, or $(\mathcal{X}' \otimes \mathcal{X}', \mathcal{Z})$-measurable, but you did not. I think this is what KaviRamaMurthy was hinting at.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk But $c$ must be $\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X$ measurable if it is $\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal X'$ measurable because $\mathcal X'$ is a sub-algebra of $\mathcal X$. I agree that the latter claim doesn't follow (and I never claimed it did).

Comment: You’re absolutely right, thanks for catching that. ~~To be more precise: I think that in your original post KaviRamaMurthy thought you meant to modify $f$ to be $(\mathcal{X}', \mathcal{X}')$-measurable, which would indeed require an altered hypothesis on the function $g$.~~ Upon rereading, I can’t figure out what KRM was worried about. As long as you’re making sure your domains and codomains line up (as measurable spaces) you can make arguments like the one you posted here without too much fear :)